# Python Clustering numerical data

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I'm following a tutorial in which the 'kmeans' algorithm is the main chunk of the overall example.  The 'rows' list is passed as the data to be clustered. The Pearson function provides the 2nd parameter, a relational coefficient and k=3 is the number of clusters. The 'bestmatches' returned from the kmeans function is a list of grouped/clustered index values corresponding to the elements from rows that belong to each cluster. As I need to make a scatter plot, I need their values. How do I return the values instead of the index's?

```
rows=[(1,1),(3,6),(11,2),(7,19),(22,11),(32,11)]

def pearson(v1,v2):

#sums
sum1=sum(v1)
sum2=sum(v2)
print(sum1)
#sums of the sqs
sum1Sq=sum([pow(v,2) for v in v1])
sum2Sq=sum([pow(v,2) for v in v2])

#sum of products
pSum=sum([v1[i]*v2[i] for i in range(len(v1))])

#calculate pearson R
num=pSum-(sum1*sum2/len(v1))
den=sqrt((sum1Sq-pow(sum1,2)/len(v1))*(sum2Sq-pow(sum2,2)/len(v1)))
if den==0: return 0

return 1.0-num/den 



def kmeans(rows,distance=pearson,k=3):
#Determine the min and max values for each point

#COunt through "rows"(data) and find min and max values
ranges=[(min([row[i] for row in rows]),max([row[i] for row in rows]))

for i in range(len(rows[0]))]    
#create k randomly placed centroids within len of 'data'
clusters=[[random.random()*(ranges[i][1]-ranges[i][0])+ranges[i][0]

for i in range(len(rows[0]))] for j in range(k)]
lastmatches=None
for t in range(100):
    print 'Iteration %d' % t

    bestmatches=[[] for i in range(k)]

    #find which centroid is the closest to each row
    for j in range(len(rows)):
        row=rows[j]
        bestmatch=0
        for i in range(k):
            d=distance(clusters[i],row)
            if d<distance(clusters[bestmatch],row): bestmatch=i

        bestmatches[bestmatch].append(j)

    if bestmatches==lastmatches: break
    lastmatches=bestmatches

    #move centroids to the avg of members
    for i in range(k):
        avgs=[0.0]*len(rows[0])
        if len(bestmatches[i])>0:
            #print(len(bestmatches[i]))
            for rowid in bestmatches[i]:
                for m in range(len(rows[rowid])):
                    avgs[m]+=rows[rowid][m]
                for j in range(len(avgs)):
                    avgs[j]/=len(bestmatches[i])
                clusters[i]=avgs

    return bestmatches
```

Comment: This tutorial is from "Programming Collective Intelligence" by Toby Segaran.  In the chapter "Discovering Groups" he covers some data mining concepts and he provides this code.

Comment: That book is reported to have a number of code errors... http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596529321 although you appear to be missing basic python experience...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Do not use k-means with pearson correlation

This may fail badly, because pearson correlation and the *mean* are incompatible and may prevent the algorithm from converging. Even worse, it may yield invalid values.

If you take the two vectors

```
1 2 3 4 5
9 8 7 6 5
```

then the mean is

```
5 5 5 5 5
```

and the resulting *mean* cannot be used with Pearson corrleation, because it is constant value.

#### K-means is only correct for *Brgeman* divergences, such as squared Euclidean. Because it is about variance minimization, not distance minimization

K-means **cannot be used with arbitrary distances**. Use k-medians (PAM) or other clustering algorithms if you have other distances.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse. I'm re-writing a distance metric function to get Euclidean. I see where bestmatches is assigned the index values too, when it's made into a list initially and then the j values are appended to it.